# polymer paper-menu-button change the default size of icon

Tags: css, polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

Is there way to set the size of polymer paper-menu-button element. I think it is the icon size is set to 24px. I wish to have it as 20px but I cannot find a way to do it.

Thanks
Dennis

Comment: you are breaking material design principle but you if you insist you can do by setting height using :shadow property in main css file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it and it worked.
Add this style to the Polymer element containing your `<paper-menu-button>` element.

```css
  paper-menu-button /deep/ core-icon[role=img] {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
  }
```

I added `[role=img]` to increase the selectivity.