# How to change size of core-icon-button and paper-icon-button for dart?

Tags: dart-polymer, core-elements

Is there a simple css styling entry to, say, halve the size of the *core-icon-button*?

I am replacing font-awesome icons with these and currently the icon size is much larger than the text, so I'm looking for a way to scale it down.

```dart
  <div horizontal layout>
    <core-icon-button icon="add-circle"></core-icon-button>
    <div horizontal layout center>Expand Entries</div>
  </div>
```

Ideally I'd like to shrink the icon inside the icon button and reduce the padding as well.

Comment: Do you want smaller icons or smaller buttons? Which iconset are you using now? `these` is not very specific ;-)

Comment: It looks like the core-icon-button wraps the core-icon. I'm using core-icon-button, but a general solution/approach would be great. The 'add-circle' above is just a core one I believe. I saw a similar unanswered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352296/polymer-paper-menu-button-change-the-default-size-of-icon with a comment that looked like a good suggestion, but not sure how to do it: "set height using :shadow property in main css". Looking for css to stick in the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how it looks when I use your code.

[image]

Whith this style in the element containing the `<core-icon-button>`

```css
  core-icon-button /deep/ core-icon[role=img] {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
  }

  core-icon-button {
    padding: 0 1px 1px 1px;
    margin: 1px;
  }
```

the icon becomes very small.
I had to add the `[role=img]` because otherwise the selectivity was to low to take effect.

Comment: Hmmm. Did not seem to work for me. With this addition the viewBox in the svg for the icon is still 24x24 and with the padding it is still 37x37. It had no effect when run in Dartium.

Comment: I didn't check other details but the icon was just a small dot afterwards.
Do you have the latest Poylmer 0.13.0 and core-elements 0.2.0+1 releases?

Comment: I wasn't, but just upgraded and no change - still big.

Comment: I take it back! Not sure what happened, it is now working. Now I need the magic to reduce the margin/whitespace. You're the man!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I can look into it tomorro. Here it's time for bed |-)